# Смысл слова "аккаунт"

Tags: значение-слов

Я собираюсь написать на своём сайте такое предложение:

**Вы можете рассказать об этой веб-странице на своём аккаунте в социальной сети.**

Можно было написать так. "Вы можете рассказать об этой веб-странице на свой странице в социальной сети." Но это некрасиво, так как два раза используется слово "страница".

Однако я не уверен, что я правильно понимаю смысл слова аккаунт. Скажите, пожалуйста, допустимо писать так, как я собираюсь написать?

Answer (score 1):

> Аккаунт (англ. account) означает «учётная запись» и представляет собой
>   набор данных о пользователе, которые тот вводит и хранит на каком-либо
>   сайте или интернет-сервисе. Другими словами, аккаунт — это
>   интернет-паспорт, который пользователь заполняет для регистрации на
>   необходимом сайте.

Другое определение:

[***Что такое аккаунт?***](http://myblaze.ru/chto-takoe-akkaunt-kak-zaregistrirovat-akkaunt-i-zachem-on-nuzhen/)

> ...Обратимся к истории этого слова. Английский вариант account
>   (дословно переведенный как «аккаунт») был впервые использован в
>   русскоязычном сегменте для обозначения банковских счетов. Но не так
>   давно, с появлением интернета, этот термин перекочевал в область
>   информационных технологий. Теперь же аккаунт – это совокупность
>   данных, которая описывает пользователя. В отличие от логина, который
>   лишь идентифицирует его, аккаунт содержит больше информации. В каждом
>   конкретном случае это может быть разный набор данных.
>
> ...Также аккаунт иногда называется профилем.

Поэтому в Вашем случае "аккаунт" (профиль, учетная запись, личный кабинет) - не очень удачное слово: записи оставляют действительно на "своей странице", а чтобы не дублировать слово, можно заменить первое:

вместо "веб-страница" - ***веб-ресурс, интернет-сервис, проект, сайт***.

Comment: Мне кажется, это неверно заменять слово веб-страница, так как веб-страница - это только одна страница сайта. А этих страниц у сайта много.

Comment: А рассказать предлагается именно об одной веб-странице.

Comment: Можно проще выйти их положения. Вместо предполагаемого "аккаунта" - никакой конкретики: *...Вы можете рассказать об этой веб-странице в любимой соцсети.*

Comment: Да. Это хороший вариант. Но слово "любимой", я считаю, плохо походит под стиль сайта. Возможно просто "в социальной сети".

Comment: Но их - соцсетей - много... Тогда *...поделиться информацией с этой веб-страницы в той соцсети, которой отдаёте предпочтение.*

Comment: А там под надписью будут значки социальных сетей. И нажатием на значок той или иной соцсети можно рассказать, не заходя в саму соцсеть.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы перефразировал:

> Вы можете поделиться ссылкой на эту статью/текст/материал на своей странице в социальной сети.

Тут под словом *страница* подразумевается *стена*, которая есть во всех основных соцсетях и одна на пользователя.

Слово *аккаунт* в данном контексте звучит неоправданно сухо и не слишком очевидно для технически малограмотного пользователя.

Comment: Я не могу так поменять, потому что одна и та жен надпись будет присоединяться в конце каждой веб-страницы сайта автоматически.

Comment: А Вы как считаете, допустимо ли вообще воспользоваться словом аккаунт? Я понимаю его так. Аккаунт - это всё, что принадлежит пользователю в соцсети. То есть практически то же самое, что "страница в соцсети".

Answer (score 1):

Аккаунт — это учетная запись, а не страница, поэтому говорить «рассказать на своём аккаунте» не совсем правильно, хотя иногда такое употребление я встречаю. Слово «веб-страница» лучше действительно как-нибудь заменить, а вместо «аккаунта» надо использовать либо «на странице», либо «в профиле».

> Вы можете рассказать об этой веб-странице на своей странице в социальной сети.
>
> Вы можете рассказать об этой веб-странице в своем профиле в социальной сети.

А может, лучше всё-таки оставить «веб-странице» и «на своей странице» вопреки тому, что здесь повтор? Иногда ведь, бывает, невозможно как-то по-другому оформить.

Comment: Значит, слово аккаунт всё-таки встречается в том же смысле, что и "страница в соцсети". Большое спасибо :-)